# React carousel multiple grids

Tags: reactjs, carousel, slideshow

Hello I'm trying to make a carousel like this with one main image on the left and two on that right one below the other, I'm trying to use react but I can't figure out how to do it can he help someone

Slideshow - Carousel white 3 post:

[image: Slideshow - Carousel white 3 post]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then come back and revisit your question. Please  share your code, progress and everythign that would help us to reproduce your problem, so that we might help you.

Comment: What after carousel run? replace by 3 other images? so you should create a component display 3 images, and create a carousel component make previous components into cycle display